# How to avoid error "The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD." using Laravel

Tags: laravel, vuejs2

I am using Laravel 7 and Vue.js 2.

When I edit a room I should update the rooms table and then to redirect to the admin page with a succesfull message.

Unfortunately when I submit the form I edit correctly the table but then the redirect fails. It appears the following error message:

```
message: "The PUT method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
```

This is my two methods in AdminController:

```
public function index()
{
    $permissions = Permission::select('id')->get();

    $rooms = Room::all();

    $languages = Language::all();

    $users = UserResource::collection(User::all());

    return view('admin')->with(['success_message' => '', 'permissions'=>$permissions, 'users'=>$users, 'rooms'=>$rooms, 'languages'=>$languages]);
}

public function edit_room (Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'id' => 'required',
        'name' => 'required'
    ]);
    
    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return response($validator->errors());
    }
    
    $room = Room::find($request->id);

    $room->name = $request->name;

    $room->save();

    $success_message = "The room " . $request->name . " has been correctly edited";

    return Redirect::route('admin')->with( ['success_message' => $success_message] );
}
```

This is the axios call in my child component:

```
        editRoom: function() {
            axios.put('edit_room', { id: this.rooms[this.index].id, name: this.roomName })
            .then((response) => {
                console.log(response);
                this.errors = response.data;
                if (Object.keys(this.errors).length === 0) {
                    alert('viva');
                    this.user = {};
                } else {
                    alert('noviva');
                }
            })
            .catch(error => {
                alert(noooooo);
                console.log(error);
                
            });
        }
```

This is my two routes in web.php:

```
Route::put('edit_room', 'AdminController@edit_room')->name('edit_room');

Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index')->name('admin');
```

This is an update of the table so I suppose I should use a PUT method but for some reason it doesn't.

Which is the best way to solve this error?

Comment: @Quentin that's an opinion. Since you have your route defined, try running `php artisan route:clear`. Maybe you cached the routes previously.

Comment: "This is an update of the table so I suppose I should use a PUT method but for some reason it doesn't." — If you were uploading a new version of the URL `edit_room`, yes, but you don't appear to be doing that.

Comment: `axios.put('edit_room'` is a relative url so if you're e.g. at `https://example.com/admin` then your request will be made to `https://example.com/admin/edit_room` . Maybe that's your intention but I think it's worth pointing out

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you send your request via XHR
So when you using

```
return Redirect::route('admin')->with( ['success_message' => $success_message]
```

it sends an response with 301 http code to redirect your browser

i think you should refactor your code like this for example

```
return 'success_message'
```

and then in your axios after console.log(response);

```
window.location.href = "http://www.your_address.com/admin";
```